# Expression inside set-body policy not working

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, policy

I dont know what i am doing wrong but expression inside to fetch value form variable is not working in set-body policy inside send-request policy. Same thing works in return response.
Scenario is I have to make 2 call where i will be passing data form first call as input to 2nd call.
E.G

```
<set-body template="liquid">
                        <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
                            <soap:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
        
                            </soap:Header>
                            <soap:Body>
                                <tem:GetSomething>
                                    <tem:contactId>
                                    @{ context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("ContactId").ToString(); }
                                    </tem:contactId>
                                </tem:GetSomething>
                            </soap:Body>
                        </soap:Envelope>
                    </set-body>
```

Here In **ContactId** is the variable I have created which contains value from the first call output.
I am getting below error for above snippet line

```
**'There was an error deserializing the object of type System.Guid. The value '
                                    @{ context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault&lt;string&gt;("ContactId").ToString(); }
                                    ' cannot be parsed as the type 'Guid'.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.**
```

Can anybody tell what is missing

Answer (score 1):

from [Codit Blog](https://www.codit.eu/blog/using-liquid-templates-in-azure-api-management/?country_sel=be)

Accessing the context variable

The context variable is also accessible from within Liquid templates.  There’s a similar object model, compared to C# expressions, however the syntax is different.  As an example, reading a query string parameter in C# works like this: `@(context.Request.Url.Query.GetValueOrDefault(“orderId”, “”)).`  Inside the Liquid template, you need to apply the following notation: `{{context.Request.Url.Query[“orderId”]}}`.